# ASP.NET vs SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

For a developer who likes working in ASP.NET/Web forms, would anyone recommend going towards a SharePoint shop?  Will I be able to keep up with latest in ASP.NET, or is SharePoint a different world?  I really like ASP.NET, but have an opportunity with SharePoint development.  Is the big change worth it on the tech/skillset end?

**UPDATE**:  I think it's better to stick with web forms, if you have a choice.  SharePoint seems to be tougher to develop[in terms of what you expect out of regular ASP.NET]/deploy/style/debug.  Why should good ASP.NET devs go to SharePoint if they don't need to?

Comment: You might want to check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535255/sharepoint-for-a-c-asp-net-developer

Comment: I did check that question, however, that person is already headed towards SharePoint and needs some help.  I'm wondering if it's worth it to go to SharePoint at all.

Comment: In the end I think it really depends on what you want as an individual. Sharepoint for many devs means much less coding and much more integration, configuration and xslt. This may throw some off since they may be interested in the programming aspect of their jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ASP.Net knowledge will help you understand some of Sharepoint, since it is based on some of the same technologies as ASP.Net.

On the negative side:

- Sharepoint has a steep learning curve
- Some developers hate it

On the positive side

- For the right scenario, you can deliver business value much faster than custom development
- Atleast in our market a Sharepoint expert will be better paid than someone who only knows ASP.net

Answer (score 3):

As someone who's been on the sharepoint train for a few years now, I'd say you'd be crazy NOT to take the opportunity. SharePoint is firmly based on asp.net and there is plenty of crossover. In fact, ASP.NET 2.0 design was large driven by the needs of WSS 3.0 - namely webparts and the system.web.hosting virtualization aspects. You will feel extremely comfortable when developing. Go for it.

-Oisin

Comment: Can you cite that ASP.NET 2.0 was driven by the WSS 3.0 needs?

Comment: @Dan:  The entire web part infrastructure in ASP.NET 2.0 was in a large part cross-pollinated from development of it within WSS 3.0.  Granted WSS extends a lot of it; but much of the base class functionality is within ASP.NET 2.0

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is different world that based on ASP.NET. You shouldn't pay attention on this. You can learn new ASP.NET features in any time you wish. I think you should change your mind to  try to solve problems needed for someones business and choose what platforms or languages to learn basing on this. No matter SharePoint or ASP.NET you can be as good as you wish in any of them.

Please don't think that I am trying to say that you will not be able to use your ASP.NET experience as a SharePoint developer. But you should understand that there will be a different world with its own rules and high level scenarios, that can be completely different than in ASP.NET. (for example Data Access scenarios has requires another model of thinking).

Comment: -1: Please clarify whether you mean that SharePoint _is_ a different world, or that it is not.

Comment: Putting -1 do not waiting for answer is not a very friendly approach ;) SharePoint is a different world as for developmet approaches, yes it is based on ASP.NET, but it has to much different concepts to be called "the same world". That's why I've tried to put all this thoughts in one, first phrase "SharePoint is different world that based on ASP.NET". It doesn't mean tha you can't apply ASP.NET expirience, but on the conceptual level some thigs will be different. (for example data access scenarious)

Comment: I recommend you clarify your answer by editing the answer. I'll remove the -1 when I see the answer clarified.

Comment: Thank's for you time and advice, I've edited comment, hope you will like it now =)

Answer (score 2):

I've been working in the SharePoint world for a good year now and I went into it head first not knowing any ASP.NET. Now that I'm getting time to teach myselfs some ASP.NET and learning the more webby concepts things in SharePoint are making a bit more sense. Although a working knowledge in ASP.NET isn't strictly needed in day to day SharePoint, at least not all of SharePoint, it is useful. I just don't find myself doing that much ASP.NET.

However that doesn't mean that you won't. There is certainly scope for it in producing SharePoint pages and modifying a site through the master pages ect. Or even web part development. SharePoint has lots of developer entry points and they vary in exposure to the underlying ASP.NET. So it really does depend on what you'll be doing.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is based on ASP.NET. You can use all ASP.NET features you're accustomed to in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with SP, plan on doing a lot more pointing and clicking and a lot less writing code. The development aspect is okay, but there's a lot to learn using the object model, CAML and some serious config.

If you like software development, writing code, being creative with your skills, I would stick with ASP.Net.

You'll also find yourself dealing with the business a lot more.