# Guide me for sharepoint development

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I have 5 years of work experience in developing WEB and WIN application using c# and .net. Now, I need to switch to Sharepoint development. Can you guide me as to where to start from and resources to be studied or any other related help. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953437/learning-sharepoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535255/sharepoint-for-a-c-asp-net-developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting resource is the [Microsoft RampUp Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx) it's a free resource that has 2 tracks for SharePoint for developers.  Each track consists of articles, slide casts and virtual labs to help you gain an understanding of what goes into developing for SharePoint.  They are not all inclusive but it should give you a good starting point.

There is also a user centric overview on the Microsoft Office Site for [SharePoint 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/cr102146081033.aspx) that can help get you an understanding of some of the features in SharePoint.

I don't know if any of the resources have been update yet for SharePoint 2010, but hopefully those will follow soon.

Also check [Microsoft Learning](http://learning.microsoft.com/Manager/Catalog.aspx?brand=learning) with SharePoint 2010 around the corner you might find free courses.  Microsoft usually releases free online courseware for new products around the time of release.

For uo to date announcements check out the [SharePoint Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/), usually there's lots of good information around there.

Good Luck.